# Indentify Mercedes Benz AMG C 63 S Coupe year model

Tags: mercedes-benz

Watching this picture how can be determined what year's model is this Mercedes Benz AMG C 63 S Coupe?

What are the specific details that can be seen in it in order to identify it?

[image]

For what I've seen in the Internet it may be the 2016 model as seen in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nnNlumfV9ZA

I assume it may be the 2016 model because the numberplate in the video is the same as in the picture above.

Furthemore, I can only notice design differences between the 2018 and 2019 model, but no clue what the design differences are between the models from 2016 to 2018 (both included).

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Since the video is 3 years old; it is a 2017 model.  I don't think the coupe was released as a 2016 model; at least not in NA.